# IntelliJ and jenkins pipeline shared library project

Tags: jenkins, intellij-idea, shared-libraries

I just start using IntelliJ, mine SharedLibrary is getting bigger and bigger so I wanted move to IDE. I get *.gdsl for autocompletion etc (basic stuff work :) )

But, when my script use @Library notation I get errors (cannot resolve symbol etc), I'm 'kid' in java world (.net daily), I think I missing some Jenkins dependency but which?

```
build.gradle

repositories {
    maven { url 'http://repo.jenkins-ci.org/releases/'}
    maven { url 'http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/'}
    maven { url 'http://jenkins-updates.cloudbees.com/download/plugins/'}
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.3.11'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.main:jenkins-core:2.97'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:pipeline-input-step:2.5'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins.workflow:workflow-cps:2.1'
    compile 'org.jenkins-ci.plugins:credentials-binding:1.10'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: ['*.jar'])
}
```

This project will only work with SharedLibrary, nothing else :) any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Add a canonical import of the annotation class Library to Jenkinsfile (located in workflow-cps-global-lib.jar)

`import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.libs.Library`

than use @Library annotation without compilation error.

[image]